# Validate website url in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, form-validation

I have used website url input in my **registration page for Magento 1**.
All things are working fine but its **validation is not working for all counties**.

**Ex:**

www.example.com (no error)

www.example.in (validation error)

**You can see here:** http://www.nutraplex.com/index.php/customerActivation/index/wholesale/

**I want it should accept all two and three digits.**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found my solution.
I went to js/prototype/validation.js

Find: validate-clean-url

Change From

```
 ['validate-clean-url', 'Please enter a valid URL. For example http://www.example.com or www.example.com', function (v) {
     return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i.test(v) || /^(www)((\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i.test(v)
 }],
```

To

```
['validate-clean-url', 'Please enter a valid URL. For example http://www.example.com or www.example.com', function (v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.([a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,3})$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i.test(v) || /^(www)((\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.([a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,3})$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i.test(v)
}],
```

and it worked.